# SQL query is returning 0 when running shell script but 6 when checking db

Tags: sql, bash, oracle, shell, unix

I'm trying to run a shell script that has a SQL query in it. Now, I can't use a SQL script in the shell script because of story requirements. I have been trying to get the shell script to return the correct count which is '6' but it is only returning '0'.

```
#!/bin/ksh
. /apps/path/config/setenv.ksh
DATE=`date "+%m%d%Y`
returnMessage="`sqlplus  username/password@$ORACLE_SID << EOF
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT SQL.OSCODE ;
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.OSCODE ;

spool /apps/path/data/test.txt
SET HEADING OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET ECHO ON
SET PAGES 0
SET LINESIZE 90

select count(*) from table where dt = to_date('06/18/2020','MM/DD/YYYY');
EOF
`
"
        exitCode=$?
        oracleError=`echo "$returnMessage" | grep ORA-`
        if [ -n "$oracleError" -o "$exitCode" -ne 0 ]; then
                log "An error occurred while looking up the $COUNT"
                log "SQLPlus Exit Code = $exitCode"
                log "SQLPlus Message is: $returnMessage"
                return 1
        fi
        export COUNT=`echo $returnMessage"
        return 0
```

The output is also given below

```
SQL> SET HEADING OFF
SQL> SET FEEDBACK OFF
SQL> SET VERIFY OFF
SQL> SET ECHO ON
SQL> SET PAGES 0
SQL> SET LINESIZE 90
SQL>
SQL> select count(*) from table where dt = to_date('06/18/2020','MM/DD/YYYY');
         0
SQL>
```

THis is the output and the code I'm using. Not sure where it is going wrong since the query should return 6;

Comment: do you get the correct count if you preface `table` with the schema name?

Comment: In the db when i type the query, yes. I get the correct count

Comment: no, what I mean is ... if you change the script and replace `table` with `schema_name.table` ... does the script return 6?

Comment: I could try that. Never thought of it that way. I'll try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Un`COMMIT`ted data is only visible within the session that created it (and will `ROLLBACK` at the end of the session if it has not been `COMMIT`ted). If you can't see the data from another session (i.e. in SQL*Plus invoked from the shell) then make sure you have issued a `COMMIT` command in the SQL client where you `INSERT`ed the data.

*Note: even if you connect as the same user, this will create a separate session and you will not be able to see the uncommitted data in the other session.*

If you have issued a `COMMIT` and still can't see the data then make sure that both the SQL Client and the shell program are connecting to the same server and the same database and are querying the same user's schema of that database.

Comment: Why are we committing when we are using only a select query?

Comment: @YasasviSunkara I assume that you have use an `INSERT` statement in another session and in that session the `SELECT` query is returning 6 rows. Well the inserted data is **ONLY** going to be visible in that session (and no others). If you `COMMIT` the data then it will be visible to other sessions (such as the session you create with the shell script).

Comment: No, did not use any insert statement. The data was there from pretty long back. Even before I joined the project. But what you say makes sense

Comment: If the data is committed then, as I said in the final paragraph, make sure you are connecting to the same server, database instance, schema and querying the same table.